# Views 3.8 hook_views_default_views() stopped working

Tags: 7, views, chaos-tool-suite

I have a default view made using the views hook hook_views_default_views().

It was working right and when I updated to Views 7.x-3.8 it stopped working.

It is not shown in structure -> views, the routes don't work too (site_url/calendar)

Seems the hook is not launching, or if it is, it does not load the view.

Updated drupal to 7.31 version, and CTools to 7.x-1.4.

Erased all the caches, drupal, views, memcached.

And it is not working.

The code looks like this:

```
// code included in my_module.views_default.inc
function my_module_views_default_views() 
{
  export = array();
  $view = new view();
  $view->name = 'planning_calendar';
  $view->description = 'Calendar with planning dates';
  $view->tag = 'Calendar';
  $view->base_table = 'node_revision';
  $view->human_name = 'Planning Calendar';
  $view->core = 7;
  $view->api_version = '3.8';
  $view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

  // view code ......

  $export[$view->name] = $view;
  return $export;
}
```

There is also this hook on the module:

```
// code included in my_module.module
function my_module_views_api() {
  return array("api" => "3.8");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the API [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7): The correct way to declare the version is by the major number only (i.e. an integer) not the entire version as a string.

```
// code included in my_module.module
function my_module_views_api() {
  return array('api' => 3);
}
```