# Alter an existing view definition

Tags: views, 8

I have an existing view to which I would like to add some contextual filters if my module gets enabled. In D7 this was possible using `hook_views_default_views`, but I can't seem to find the equivalent in D8. Is this possible in D8?

Comment: Yes, but it's not easy to figure out how. It involves adding handler to the viewExecutable object in the view_pre_view hook. This may get you started: http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/drupal-8-programmatically-adding-views-footer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing a view by using `hook_views_default_views()` is no longer possible. In D8 views are configuration entities. This means when a module wants to provide a view, it puts a yml file in /config/install.

If you want to change a view in code, load the view, change it and save it.

```
$view = View::load('test_filter_taxonomy_index_tid');
$display =& $view->getDisplay('default');
$display['display_options']['filters']['tid']['type'] = 'textfield';
$view->save();
```

A third alternative is to change the view directly in configuration, for example replace it with the content of a yml file:

```
$config_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/config/optional/views.view.myview.yml';
$data = \Symfony\Component\Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($config_path));
\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('views.view.myview')->setData($data)->save(TRUE);
```

The last option might be the easiest for your use case. You can configure the view in ui, export it to a yml file and use this file to overwrite the configuration of an existing view in `hook_install()`.